# How to find if a pixel is entirely within another pixel when comparing for example two GeoTIFF raster maps?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, intersection, pixel

Using GDAL and/or Python
Red: GeoTIFF raster Map layer 1
Blue: GeoTIFF raster Map layer 2

[image]

Comment: Pixel-in-pixel is not a common GIS operation. The relationship will occur infrequently, but regularly, depending on the origins and pixel dimensions. I can't think of any possible use for this information. You'll need to use Python, and include your code in the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no rotation, if you have the coordinates of the center of your pixel, you can check that both the absolute difference between the X or Y coordinates of your "blue" pixel" and the "red" pixel is smaller than the difference between the half-width of the "red pixel" and the "blue" pixel (in the X and Y direction).

gdalinfo will give you the necessary information.